# Replace 2 home stoves with 1 commercial

Tags: electrical, wiring, stove

We have 2 household ranges sidebyside on 2 50amp breakers. We want to replace both stoves with 1 60in commercial stove with burners/griddle and 2 ovens below. Without doing to much rewiring..is this possible.

Comment: Will depend on the power specifications of the new stove.  Imagine a bigger breaker and larger gauge wires, but might be lucky and can just plug into one circuit(buy a lotto ticket) you have now.

Comment: We can answer (and I tried) for a *typical* unit.  Commercial units try to maximize cooking capacity for a given space, and we can see what resulting typical draws are.  Say 30kW.    Residential 60in units try to maximize *apparent* cooking capacity while remaining within a 50A total profile.  That's why 60in ones are almost always gas or part gas.

Comment: IIRC (having looked into this myself, since I like commercial ranges) you'll have a big hole in the "follow manufacture's installation instructions" part of code, which for real commercial ranges (as opposed to home status symbol looks-kinda-like) tend to explicitly forbid installation in a residential/non-commercial setting. They also tend to require a commercial hood, which may cost as much as or more than the range does.

Comment: What make and model is the new stove you're looking at?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on a lot of things but for a 60 inch *commercial all-electric range*, 30kW is typical.  Plus or minus a lot, but attempting to answer a very general question.   For that on a residential single-phase 240V circuit you're going to need an entire 150A service panel just for the range.

Most of these are able to accept single or three phase service.   I don't think you'll find one with dual independent single phase power inputs.  Maybe you could rig it up in a warranty-voiding sort of way.  Or maybe not warranty-voiding.  It requires some careful planning and the manufacturer would have to agree but it ought to work as long as the loads can be split into two groups each requiring no more than 9600W.  (So the entire unit can be at most 19kW).   If the unit has both single-phase and 3-phase wiring buses, you would use each bus for one circuit and half the loads.

Question: Were your two 50A circuits designed so that they could both be maxed out (80A total actual continuous consumption) and you still have enough service capacity for the rest of your home to function normally?

My suggestion: gas.

Comment: They do not build range for residential use needing 150 Amp

Comment: @Ruskes They don't. But it is a *commercial* range.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it is NOT commercial, only commercial-depth.

Comment: @Ruskes how do you know? OP has not provided a make /model.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact just going by the OP calling it burners.

Comment: The example in @Ruskes  answer is residential but this answer focuses on commercial because OP said "commercial" and commercial ranges have burners of course.    OP seems to have vanished unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run your plan by your home insurance agent.  Your policy may not insure commercial equipment.  I would want something in writing.

If you’re buying new, check whether the warranty is valid for being in a home.

Do you have the required clearance around the stove?